# How can I call a function when the last image of several images loads?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to call a function when all of a specific set of images have loaded. At the moment I am simply using .onload for the very last image, and it works 99% of the time, but sometimes there are problems. What is the best way to go about this? I realise I could create a .onload for every image, and then check inside the function if all the other images have loaded, but I feel like there must be a more efficient way.

Here is my code:

```
P1LCImage.src = "images/" + P1LC + "-card.png";
P1RCImage.src = "images/" + P1RC + "-card.png";
P2LCImage.src = "images/" + P2LC + "-card.png";
P2RCImage.src = "images/" + P2RC + "-card.png";
P3LCImage.src = "images/" + P3LC + "-card.png";
P3RCImage.src = "images/" + P3RC + "-card.png";
P4LCImage.src = "images/" + P4LC + "-card.png";
P4RCImage.src = "images/" + P4RC + "-card.png";
P5LCImage.src = "images/" + P5LC + "-card.png";
P5RCImage.src = "images/" + P5RC + "-card.png";
P6LCImage.src = "images/" + P6LC + "-card.png";
P6RCImage.src = "images/" + P6RC + "-card.png";
blankCardImage.src = "images/blank-card.png";
protectedCardImage.src = "images/protected-card.png";
voteCount1.src = "images/voteCount1.png";
voteCount2.src = "images/voteCount2.png";
voteCount3.src = "images/voteCount3.png";
voteCount4.src = "images/voteCount4.png";
voteCount5.src = "images/voteCount5.png";
voteCount6.src = "images/voteCount6.png";
voteCount6.onload = function () {
    drawTable();        
    };
```

Comment: You could count the loaded images with a counter, and when all is loaded, invoke a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an onload to every image, and have them each increment a counter. when the counter reaches the number of images, all images have loaded, and you call `drawTable()`

Sample Code:

```
var numImgs = 6;
var numLoaded = 0;

function imgLoaded() {

if(++numLoaded === numImgs)
  drawTable();        
};

voteCount1.onload = imgLoaded;
voteCount2.onload = imgLoaded;
voteCount3.onload = imgLoaded;
voteCount4.onload = imgLoaded;
voteCount5.onload = imgLoaded;
voteCount6.onload = imgLoaded;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how many images you need to show, you can follow this approach:

```
var counter = 0;
var TOTAL_IMAGES = 20;
function imageOnLoad() {
    if (++counter >= TOTAL_IMAGES) {
        drawTable();
    }
}
```

Of course `TOTAL_IMAGES` may be variable, in this case you might use an array length, or something similar. I would attach the event on a DOM class, so you don't need to specify the `onload` event on every single image. For example let's assume that the pictures are wrapped in a div with the id of `gallery`. In this case, you can do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#gallery img').forEach(function() {
    this.onclick = imageOnLoad;
});
```

Comment: I like your answer. it is very comprehensive.